# Are Molex PicoBlade connectors compatible with JST GH?

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

I've read that Molex PicoBlade is often confused with JST GH as they both have the same 1.25mm pitch and similar connectors.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector

Will a JST GH female terminal fit in a Molex PicoBlade male terminal?  Although the incompatibility isn't explicitly listed in Wikipedia (and other articles), I suspect it is implied.

Comment: Im surprised that made it to wiki. Completely original research citation needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

Yes - you can plug them together.

No - would you want to fly on an aircraft where the JST GH female terminal was mated to a Molex PicoBlade in the auto pilot?